# How to know whether a client is disconnected or not on the server/client side?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have a situation like a Client1 sends data to client2 and from there the data is sent to a Server.Now from the server the data is sent to other multiple clients.

So,now when Client1 is connected to client2 and after sending some
 data if the client1 disconnects how to know that the client1 is
 disconnected in client2?

My Client1 code snippet is:

```
               InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
               MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
               socket.joinGroup(address);//join a Multicast group and send the group salutations
               byte[] data;
               System.out.print("Enter data: ");
               String str = (br.readLine());
               DatagramPacket packet;
               //send the packet
               data = new byte[1024];
               data = str.getBytes();
               packet = new DatagramPacket(data,str.length(),address,port);
               socket.send(packet);
```

My Client2 code snippet is:

```
  InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
  byte[] data = new byte[1024];
  DatagramPacket packet = new  DatagramPacket(data,data.length);
  MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
  socket.joinGroup(address);//join a Multicast group and send the group salutations
  // receive the packets
  socket.receive(packet);
  str = new String(packet.getData(),0,packet.getLength());
  System.out.println(ipname+" with portnumber  "+port + " sent : "+str);
```

Now, if client1 gets connected to client2 and after some time it disconnects how to know that client1 got disconnected in client2?

I have already used `isConnected(), isbound(), isClosed()` and also `isReachable(int timeout)` methods. But none of them helped me.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Nobody is connected to anything. You're using UDP. It's a connectionless protocol. `isConnected()` and friends don't tell you anything about the state of the connection, only of your socket. Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JavaDoc for`DatagramPacket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html) says:

> Datagram packets are used to implement a connectionless packet
>   delivery service.

A connectionless protocol doesn't have a connection that can be closed. If you're building your own protocol on top of UDP/DatagramPacket, make it part of your protocol to 'close' the session.